# How to find the table i want in an sql server using entity framework

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I am using a method which its purpose it to read from tables. The method has an input parameter, a string which will hold the name of the table I will pass and I want to read from. There are multiple tables. My code so far:

```
public List<dataTable> GetData(string name)
    {
        TableEntities db = new TableEntities();
        db.Database.Connection.Open();
        foreach (var readDb in db.SOMETHING_HERE) //here it should find the table which is equal to the table I'm passing as string name
        {
            dataTable data = new dataTable();
            data.name = readDb.name;
```

There are many option at db. but I don't know which fits my needs.

Comment: Can you show us the `DbSet` defined within your `context`, `TableEntities`

Comment: Have you ever used Entity Framework before?

Comment: I don't know how to do that. Any info? @cost I didn't go into much detail of Entity Framework, i just wrote and read and that was/is sufficient.

Comment: So you want to pass in a string with the the name of the table you wish to read from? And you want to know how to dynamically pick which table to use with your `db` object?

Comment: That is correct. I want the option to choose from which table to read using the string parameter as the name of the table.

Comment: You should be able to do that using reflection

Comment: Hey thanks that seems to be what I need.

Comment: It's usually a sign of a broken data model if you have multiple tables with identical structures such that they're used interchangably. Usually, you'll find that part of the *data* has ended up mistakenly embedded in the table names. I.e. if you were modelling an organisation, you probably shouldn't have separate `MaleEmployees` and `FemaleEmployees` tables.

Comment: I'm storing sensor data for different companies. The number of sesors is different for every company. I tried to keep it simple and managable as i'm not very familiar with databases.

Comment: Could anyone provide an example for my case??? I can't get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use reflection to achieve that: [MSDN Reflection reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/ms173183.aspx)

You may want to try something along these lines: (assuming sample tables Employees and Departments)

```
public List<dataTable> GetData(string name)
{
    using(TableEntities db = new TableEntities())
    {
        if(new Employees().GetType().ToString().Equals(name))
            //Do query
    }
}
```

Comment: Reflection seems to be what I'm looking for but I can't find an example to work on. At least something that is similar to my needs. Thanks for the `using` statement.

Comment: Updated with a possible example

Answer (score 0):

It's not pretty, but you can try this:

```
        using (TableEntities db = new TableEntities())
        {
            var type = Type.GetType("namespace." + tableName);

            var query = db.Database.SqlQuery(type, "SELECT * FROM " + tableName);

            foreach (var row in query)
            {
                PropertyInfo prop = type.GetProperty("NAME");
                string name = (string)prop.GetValue(row);
            }
        }
```